# handling fast move of mouse on mousemove while resizinng an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to have a resizeable modal only on height so I did write some code but while trying to grow it to the bottom because it's going fast and out of the element it doesn't have any impact, also I have seen codes like this but they work properly [like this](https://htmldom.dev/make-a-resizable-element/) I don't know what I'm missing.

also, I want to ask; is it the right way of doing resizeable components in react? I did try to write it with states but I faced some problems like it was growing unexpectedly.

```js
import React, { FC, useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from "react";

import { PrimitivesT } from "../Table/Table";
interface ModalProps {
  children: JSX.Element | PrimitivesT;
  display: boolean;
  width: string;
  height: string;
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  boxShadow?: boolean;
}

const Modal: FC<ModalProps> = ({
  children,
  display = false,
  // initial height
  height = "0",
  width = "0",
  x,
  y,
  boxShadow = true,
}) => {

  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const styles = useMemo<React.CSSProperties>(
    () => ({
      display: display ? "block" : "none",
      height: height,
      width,
      minHeight: "15px",
      position: "absolute",
      left: x,
      top: y,
      boxShadow: boxShadow ? "1px 1px 10px 5px var(--gray)" : undefined,
      borderRadius: "5px",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      zIndex: 900,
    }),
    [display, height, width, x, y, boxShadow]
  );

  const bottomStyle = useMemo<React.CSSProperties>(
    () => ({
      cursor: "row-resize",
      width: "100%",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: "0",
      left: "0",
      height: "5px",
    }),
    []
  );

  const onMouseDown =
    useCallback((): React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> => {
      let y = 0;
      let h = 60;

      const onMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        const YDir = e.clientY - y;
        if (ref.current) ref.current.style.height = `${h + YDir}px`;
      };

      const onMouseUp = () => {
        try {
          ref.current?.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          ref.current?.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      };

      return e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        const bounding = ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (bounding?.height) h = bounding?.height;
        y = e.clientY;
        ref.current?.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        ref.current?.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
      };
    }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      style={styles}
      data-testid="Modal"
      onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
      {children}
      <div style={bottomStyle} onMouseDown={onMouseDown()}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Why not just use the css `resize: vertical;`? Javascript seems overkill... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: because I want to do other things based on the height of the modal element I need  to have access to the height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it didn't work that way because it's modal and it has to be fixed or absolute so I change the element that I was attaching event listeners instead of the resizeable target I used document object.

```js
  const onMouseDown =
    useCallback((): React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> => {
      let y = 0;
      let h = 60;

      const onMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        const YDir = e.clientY - y;
        if (ref.current) ref.current.style.height = `${h + YDir}px`;
      };

      const onMouseUp = () => {
        try {
          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      };

      return e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        const bounding = ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (bounding?.height) h = bounding?.height;
        y = e.clientY;
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
      };
    }, []);
```